# Code generation with copy_with_extension_gen problem

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add new variable for my copyWith class, I am already using freezed class.

The problem is that after running `flutter pub run build_runner build` I get:

"[INFO] Found 24 declared outputs which already exist on disk. This is likely because the`.dart_tool/build` folder was deleted, or you are submitting generated files to your source repository.
Delete these files?"

How to add new variable for my copyWith class?